# Cocos2d replaceScene not releasing the old scene

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have a box2d-cocos2d game that has several levels. My levels are layers that use Box2d features inherited from another class. For example the first layer looks like:

```
Level1Layer : Box2DLevel : Box2DLayer : CCLayer : CCNode : NSObject
```

My problem is that the layer is not releasing when it should.For example if I replay the Level with this code:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:[CCTransitionFade transitionWithDuration:0.5f scene:[[self class] node]]];
```

Then the memory footprint just increases.The same thing happens also if I have a circle like menu -> Level 1 -> menu -> Level 1 and my app just crashes after a time because the insufficient memory.I tracked the dealloc methods with NSLogs, but every dealloc method is called, when I replace the scene.
My Log looks like:

```
*** DEALLOC ***<Level1Layer = 0x1cdcfe70 | Tag = -1>
2013-08-26 12:05:57.089 Myapp[6334:907] 
***BOX2DLEVEL DEALLOC ***<Level1Layer = 0x1cdcfe70 | Tag = -1>
2013-08-26 12:05:57.093 Myapp[6334:907] ***BOX2DLAYER DEALLOC ***
<Level1Layer = 0x1cdcfe70 | Tag = -1>
```

I'm really stuck, because on iPhone 4 after playing 3 levels the app crashes.
How can I solve this problem? Any solutions and pointers are appreciated.

Level 1 dealloc:

```
-(void)dealloc{
    NSLog(@"\n*** DEALLOC ***%@",self);
    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Box2dLevel dealloc:

```
-(void) dealloc{
    NSLog(@"\n***BOX2DLEVEL DEALLOC ***%@",self);
    [self removeChild:_label cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:labelForCoins cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:labelForTime cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:freezeCountDown cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:freezedMask cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:_backGround cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:darkLayer cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:flashlayer cleanup:YES];
    [self removeChild:skillsMenu cleanup:YES];
    [arrayForObjects release];
    [skillsMenuArray release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Box2dLayer dealloc:

```
-(void) dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"***BOX2DLAYER DEALLOC ***\n%@",self);
    if (debugDraw) {
        delete debugDraw;
        debugDraw = NULL;
    }
    if (mouseJoint) {
        world->DestroyJoint(mouseJoint);
        mouseJoint = NULL;
    }
    if (groundBody) {
        world->DestroyBody(groundBody);
        groundBody = NULL;
    }
    if (referenceBody) {
        world->DestroyBody(referenceBody);
        referenceBody = NULL;
    }
    if (bombSensor) {
        world->DestroyBody(bombSensor);
        bombSensor = NULL;
    }
    if (laserSensor) {
        world->DestroyBody(laserSensor);
        laserSensor = NULL;
    }
    if (_contactListener) {
        free(_contactListener);
        _contactListener = NULL;
    }
    [self removeChild:_obj cleanup:YES];
    [super dealloc];
    NSLog(@"\n***Box2dLayer superclass deallocated");
```

Comment: use the CCTextureCache dump method, maybe you simply have too many textures loaded

Comment: Well if you see a dealloc log every time it should be called than you might have a large memory usage elsewhere as stated by LearnCocos2D or maybe something in your dealloc method is failing without you knowing it. Can you post your dealloc method ?

Comment: @giorashc I posted the dealloc methods. It seems that box2dLayer's [super dealloc] is not called.

Comment: Did you try to debug it step by step ? in what line does it fail in the dealloc chain ? (btw in your level dealloc you call removeAllChildrenWithCleanup so there is no use of doing that again in the super dealloc methods with removeChild)

Comment: are you sure, you don't have a CCDictionary or CCArray class retaining them. the only reason an object won't get released is when its retain count is not "0". try adding logs for retainCount in your dealloc. This should give some insight.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `[Level1layer scene]` instead of `[[self class] node]` (So does the sample project do it)